# Get the total number of items in a strongly typed observable array of items in Knockout.js

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, knockout.js

please i need help on how to display the total length of an observable array collections in my view. whenever i try, the result is always zero. Below is the sample.
MyVM.js file

```
//Model
var Course = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    self.title = ko.observable(data.Title);
    self.creditHour = ko.observable(data.CreditHour);
self.result = ko.observableArray(data.result);
    return self;
}
//View Model
var CourseList = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.courses = ko.observableArray([]);

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/Student/Register_For_Courses',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: 'json',
        traditional: true,
        success: function (data) {
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(data, function (data) {
                self.courses.push(new Course(data))          
            });

        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(err.status + " : " + err.statusText);
        }

    });

    //Get total of array collection
    tHour = self.courses().length;
    // button functions
    removeCourse = function (course) { self.courses.remove(course); }


}

$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new CourseList());
});
```

Here is my View

```
<tr>
   Total CH<td data-bind="text:tHour"></td>
</tr>
```

problem is that tHour is returning 0 instead of the expect length of the array.

Comment: *"Get the total number of items in a strongly typed observable array of items in knockoujs" Not sure what you mean by "strongly typed" there. This is JavaScript. Nothing is strongly typed.

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

1. Either use `courses().length`:

   ```
   <td data-bind="text: courses().length"></td>
   ```
2. Use a computed:

   ```
   self.tHour = ko.pureComputed(function() {
       return self.courses().length;
   });
   ```

---

Side note: Your template is invalid. You can't have `Total CH` directly inside a `tr` (e.g., not inside a `td` or `th`).

Side note 2: Your `tHour` was an [implicit global](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html);<sup>1</sup> you meant `self.tHour = ...`.

<sup>1</sup> *That's a post on my anemic little blog.*